# Identify this Android Widget

Tags: android, widget

[image]
I have seen the above marked (Encircled in Red) widget in quiet a few applications, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [FastScroll](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcPIvGRwrxA), standard feature of ListView, [here](http://androidwizard.net/2010/06/fast-scroll-list-view/)  you can see how it can be implemented.

Comment: myListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

Comment: Literally yes, but you need to do some work to enable behavior like in video.